# how to load files from any directory in c programme

Tags: c

i want to change this code below for the inwashfile to be able to load from any directory instead of loading from the tech_projects environmental variable.

```
  /**Get projects directory from environment variable****************/
 strcpy(pjects.arr, getenv("Tech_Projects"));

  pjects.arr[strlen(pjects.arr)] = '\0';

  if (strcmp(inwashfile.arr, "null") != 0)
  {
    for (d=2;d<inwashfile.len;d++)
    {
      tempfile.arr[d-2] = inwashfile.arr[d];
    }      
    memset(inwashfile.arr, '\0', 255);    

    strcpy(inwashfile.arr, pjects.arr);
    strcat(inwashfile.arr, tempfile.arr);

    inwashfile.len = strlen(inwashfile.arr);
    inwashfile.arr[inwashfile.len] = '\0';
    do_wash[0] = 'T';
  }
  else
  {
    do_wash[0] = 'F';
  }
printf("3\n");
  do_wash[1] = '\0';
```

Comment: @Scott, thank you for fixing the horrible formatting. @Monica, what is the point of code like `pjects.arr[strlen(pjects.arr)] = '\0';`? Do you know how strlen() works?

Comment: Is that code you wrote, or did it come from somewhere else and you're asking for help understanding it?

Comment: this code was always there and working,but the files were loaded from an environmental variable "Tech_Projects" which is mapped as a p:\ drive on each users computer,so when they ran this program it would automatically open folder in the p:\ drive to load the inwashfile.............so now i need help to change to be able to load the files from any directory,i just nid to change the file load location from being the p:\ drive to load from any directories.hope this explains .

Answer (score 0):

```
 /**Get projects directory from environment variable****************/
 /* You need to replace this line with wherever you want to get the
    file name from. Either request it from the user, pull it from a
    configuration file or read it from the command line */
 strcpy(pjects.arr, getenv("Tech_Projects"));

  /* this line does absolutely nothing. strlen() relies on the string
     already being null-terminated */
  pjects.arr[strlen(pjects.arr)] = '\0';

  if (strcmp(inwashfile.arr, "null") != 0)
  {
    for (d=2;d<inwashfile.len;d++)
    {
      tempfile.arr[d-2] = inwashfile.arr[d];
    }      
    memset(inwashfile.arr, '\0', 255);    

    strcpy(inwashfile.arr, pjects.arr);
    strcat(inwashfile.arr, tempfile.arr);

    inwashfile.len = strlen(inwashfile.arr);
    inwashfile.arr[inwashfile.len] = '\0';
    do_wash[0] = 'T';
  }
  else
  {
    do_wash[0] = 'F';
  }
printf("3\n");
  do_wash[1] = '\0';
```

Comment: i tried replacing the line with : strcpy(pjects.arr,getdir([cdirectory,[ctext,[ccaption,[nflag,[clrootonly]]]]])), but it give an error for 
gc_load.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _getdir
gc_load.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Answer (score 0):

It could be

```
strcpy(pjects.arr, argv[ 1 ] );
```

and the directory named could be passed from the command line, e.g.

```
$ myprogram /user/foo
```